# How to use child selectors in JSS

Tags: javascript, jss

I'm experimenting with JSS to see if it is realistic to migrate a Sass code base. I have a very basic example of a CSS style that, when hovered, modifies the style of a child node.

```css
span {
  color: red;
}

button:hover span {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<button>
  <span>Click Me</span>
</button>
```

I am unsure how to write this in JSS. Something I have tried looks like:

```js
const styles = {
  button: {
    '&:hover': {
      span: {
        color: 'blue',
      }
    }
  },
  span: {
    color: 'red',
  }
}

const { classes } = jss.createStyleSheet(styles).attach()

document.body.innerHTML = `
  <button class=${classes.button}>
    <span class=${classes.span}>Click Here</span>
  </button>
`
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Have you tried doing:

```
const styles = {
  button: {
    '&:hover span': {
       color: 'blue',
    }
  },
  span: {
    color: 'red',
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! How would it work if it was a class name that did not match an element selector. For instance if it was `someClass`.

Comment: @JonSakas, prefix the class with a $. For example: `"&:hover $someClass"`

Comment: when hovered on the button, is this code gonna change all span element's color or the span elements which are nested in the button?

Comment: hi @deowk, is there any way to access the parent element using the child element in JSS

Answer (score 13):

As mentioned in the comment by @cwouter, if it was a class name, you can do something like this.

```js
const styles = {
  button: {
    '&:hover $some_class_name': {
       color: 'blue',
    }
  },
  some_class_name: {
    color: 'red',
  }
}
```